# How to delete all text before certain symbol?

Tags: lua

Hello i need to delete text before certain symbol
Something like this:

Something:somethingtoo --> somethingtoo
Something2:somethingtoo2 --> somethingtoo2

There are about 100 somethings and i need to delete everything before : so i don't know how

Others used replace() but i am too lazy to write all 100 examples so can you help me if there is a way?
`//this is the code others used Something = "Something:somethingtoo" SomethingNew = replace(Something, "Something", "" print(SomethingNew)`

Comment: `s:gsub("Something.-:","")`

Comment: Lua doesn't have "replace". What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `string.gsub` to replace something.

Here's the example

```lua
-- To call the function, you can do `string.gsub` or `(''):gsub ( stringVar:gsub )`

local myString = "Something:other"
local otherString = string.gsub(myString,"^Something","")

print(otherString)
```

Here's some references about String library and String patterns:

- https://www.tutorialspoint.com/string-gsub-function-in-lua-programming
- https://www.lua.org/pil/20.2.html